# how to debug node program running inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I am running some node docker containers, by docker-compose.yml. How can I debug that node instance. I am new to docker, need some help.

Comment: in other words you want to know how to connect to your container process?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can do remote debugging using different tools such as `console.log()`, VSCode debugger, Chrome dev tools, etc.

In my opinion, using the `node inspect script.js` is the best. It lets you debug through Chrome dev tools.

[Here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#command-line-options) you can find more about `inspector`, and [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/how-to-debug-a-node-js-app-in-a-docker-container/) is a good tutorial on debugging a containerized Nodejs app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [Rookout](https://www.rookout.com/)? It supports Node on Docker and kind of lets you create virtual log lines on the fly without restarting or changing the code to add them.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a node application running inside a docker container, you would have to run node debug mode with the `--inspect=0.0.0.0`, and then expose the port `9229` in your `docker-compose` file.

You can use Google Chrome Inspector with `chrome://inspect` to access your app.

Have a look a the great article from RaisingStack on "[How to Debug a Node.js app in a Docker Container](https://blog.risingstack.com/how-to-debug-a-node-js-app-in-a-docker-container/)"

Answer (score 0):

Expose port **9229**, like this:

> docker run -it -p 9229:9229 --name container_name node bash

then, inside container:

> node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js